# How can i test mail sending using phpunit?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a mailable class which I use to send an email to users, which works fine. I want to write some phpunit test to check if the mail is actually sent. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good explanation in the documentation.

My mailable class:

```
class UserInvite extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $inviteMessage;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @param string $inviteMessage
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, string $inviteMessage)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->inviteMessage = $inviteMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.mail');
    }
}
```

Test:

```
/** @test */
public function it_sends_invite()
{
    Mail::fake();
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $inviteMessage = 'test';

    Mail::assertSent(new UserInvite($user, $inviteMessage));
}
```

Error:

> ErrorException: Object of class App\Mail\UserInvite could not be converted to string

Solution:

```
/** @test */
    public function it_sends_invite()
    {
        Mail::fake();

        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        Mail::to($user)->send(new UserInvite($user, 'message'));

        Mail::assertSent(UserInvite::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing for sent mails, you don't pass a whole mailable instance. PHPUnit wouldn't be able to compare a full object anyway. Instead, you just pass the fully qualified class name:

```
// use App\Mail\UserInvite;

Mail::assertSent(UserInvite::class);
```

Comment: I tried this one, but got: 
The expected [App\Mail\UserInvite] mailable was not sent.
Failed asserting that false is true.

I thought it's because we should transfer $user and $invite to constructor.

Comment: No, it means exactly what it states. What does the code look like, which sends the mail?

Comment: Mail::to($user)->send(new UserInvite($user, $inviteMessage)); (works fine)

test :

Mail::fake();
Mail::assertSent(PasswordReset::class);  (doesn't work)

Comment: In your test, you are not calling any application code. You are just assigning some variables and asserting a mail is sent. That's not going to work. If that doesn't solve the issue, I'm afraid more context of your sending code is needed.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I added code which sends email. In laravel documentation i didn't see it.

Comment: What you are doing in your test is quite useless. This is not what the `Mail::assertSend()` test is meant for. What you are supposed to do is test a method which sends a mail under certain conditions. Imagine you have a scheduled command which calls an external API and ensures it is online. If the response of the call is negative (like a 500 Internal Error), a mail will be sent. Testing this method would require you to assert that a mail is sent on error or not sent if everything is fine. But just sending a mail from the test itself is useless. The framework code is already tested.

Comment: Yeah, i know, but it was my first step )) Thank you!!